# How to enable bullet styles in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: document, word, formatting

Intro: I'm running a publishing service using Sharepoint 2010 and recently tried to copy and paste contents from Word 2010 into an article.

Problem: After pasting the content, it did not retain the different bullet styles such as roman numerals and alphabet (a. b. c. etc.) and isntead it converted everything into numbering bullets.

I've seen this work else where and looked through the site settings but there was nothing there to "enable" such option.

Would very much apprecait it if someone could shed some light on the bulleting system for Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Start by editing your page using the menu **"Site Actions > Edit Page"**. Select the area you want to edit and the Ribbon enables. In the **Editing Tool > Format Text** section you have the bullit as you are used to in Word:

[image]